# How do I put only true objects in a new listview

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have here an arraylist that is shown in a listview, when I give long click a dialog is displayed it contains the option of favorite that when selected the object is marked as true, how do I only display the items marked in my ActivityFavoritos?

### MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    ArrayList<memes> item;
    ArrayAdapter<memes> arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_main);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lv);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();

        item = new ArrayList<>();
        //itens
        item.add(new memes("Fique apertado sobre o meme para compartilhar", R.raw.sharebagui));
        item.add(new memes("2 mil anos", R.raw.milanos));
        item.add(new memes("Acelera jesus", R.raw.acelera_jesus));
        item.add(new memes("Azideia", R.raw.asideia));
        item.add(new memes("Acertou mizeravi", R.raw.mizeravi));

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        //play audio
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
                playSong(position);
            }
        });
  //PROGRESS

        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, final int position, long l) {
           //PROGRESS
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            builder.setTitle("Olá, Marilene!");
            builder.setItems(Nomes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    switch (which) {
                        case 0: // Delete
                            sendWhatsAppAudio(position);
                            break;
                        case 1: // Copy
                            item.get(position).setmIsFavourite(true);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });


            AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
            builder.show();

            return true;

        }
    });
    }

    public void playSong(int songIndex) {

        mp.reset();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, arrayAdapter.getItem(songIndex).getResId());

        mp.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mp.release();
    }

}
```

### memes.class

```
    public class memes{

    private String nome;
    private int resID;
    private Boolean mIsFavourite;

    memes(String nome, int resID){

        this.nome = nome;
        this.resID = resID;
    }

    public String getNome(){
        return nome;
    }

    int getResId(){
        return resID;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return nome;
    }

    public Boolean getmIsFavourite() {
        return mIsFavourite;
    }

    public void setmIsFavourite(Boolean mIsFavouriteResource) {
        this.mIsFavourite = mIsFavouriteResource;
    }

}
```

this is my progress so far I am confused of what I should do in the favorite activity.

### ActivityFavoritos.class

```
public class ActivityFavoritos {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(activity_favoritos);

        lv = findViewById(R.id.lvf);

        if (list.get(position).getmIsFavourite()) {
            //do want you want when its true
        } else {
            //do want your code when its false.
        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, item);
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add a boolean property, isFavorite, on your memes. if true, it means that it's your favorite, otherwise it will not be displayed.

Comment: how would I do that? Do you have any tutorials to tell me?

Comment: @Welyson Add private boolean isFavourite to the memes.class along with the accessor and mutator methods. From there add the on double-click or whatever activity you want and have it change the selected object's isFavourite property to true. Perform a check at runtime or when you need to check if the object is a favourite to see if the object's isFavourite is set to true. If it's true, add it to the favourite's menu.

Answer (score 1):

In your **`memes class`** declare variable

```
private Boolean mIsFavourite;
```

And declare getter and setter method for same.

```
  public Boolean getmIsFavourite() {
        return mIsFavourite;
    }

    public void setmIsFavourite(Boolean mIsFavouriteResource) {
        this.mIsFavourite = mIsFavouriteResource;
    }
```

Now on Double click set value of that **item to True**

```
item.get(position).setmIsFavourite(true);
```

In your second Activity just check value of this by using **`getmIsFavourite()`**

**EDIT :**

To use this `getmIsFavourite()`

```
if(list.get(position).getmIsFavourite())
{
     //do want you want when its true
}else{
     //do want your code when its false.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm layman in java, how would I use getmIsFavourite () in the second activity? @Dipali s